# Cant remove Google Chrome notifications

Tags: notifications, samsung-galaxy-s-9

I got notifications saying "waiting for network" when I tried to download a video file.

How do I get rid of those notifications without restarting the device?

They seem to be unclearable. Why?

Is there a notification removal app that I can use?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have you checked the Download page from the Chrome itself if there are pending downloads?

Comment: I managed to cancel the downloads. Still I am seeking for an app that can clear any type of notifications.